# How to gzip a directory/folder using pako module in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, pako

I am trying to gzip my folder with the help of Pako library. I couldn't found any related content about it. Can someone explain me how to use pako to gzip directory. I am using it in my lambda function along with EFS.

```
    let bundle = fs.readdirSync(tempDir);
    let zippedFile = pako.gzip(bundle);
```

My folder location looks like this **data/temp/**

**Error**

```
TypeError: strm.input.subarray is not a function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `fs.readdirSync()` to list files in the directory, then check the stat of each file before compressing it using `fs.lstatSync()`. I have tested this locally on my mac.

Then you can write the compressed file to your file system.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const pako = require('pako');
let files = fs.readdirSync('/tmp/');
let fileContent = '';
files.forEach(file => {
    let path = '/tmp/' + file;
    let stats = fs.lstatSync(path);
    if (stats.isFile()) {
        let data = fs.readFileSync(path);
        fileContent += data;
    }
});
let zippedFile = pako.gzip(fileContent);
const stream = fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/dir.gz');
stream.write(zippedFile);
stream.end();
```